cancel ongoing API requests with dio cancel token in flutter
I have to Tab in Tabbar button, and when user click on each tab is send a request with different query params, now if user tap of get_cars and quickly before getting data click on tab of get_drivers the data of get_cars show and after that data of get_drivers show, but i WANT===>
when user click on another option, cancel the previous requests and send the current option request.
now I just want it on get requests
and that is my code and I use Dio package


import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:untitled/core/error/exceptions.dart';
import 'package:untitled/core/platform/network_urls.dart';
import 'package:untitled/routes/app_router.dart';
import 'package:untitled/routes/app_router.gr.dart';
import '../get_it/get_it.dart';
import '../local_storage/keys.dart';
import '../local_storage/local_storage.dart';

abstract class HttpRequests {
  Future<Response> get(String url);

  Future<Response> post(String url, {Object? body});

  Future<Response> delete(String url);

  Future<Response> patch(String url, {Object? body});

  void cancelRequests(); // Method to cancel requests
}

class HttpRequestsImp extends HttpRequests {
  final LocalStorage localStorage = sl<LocalStorage>();
  late CancelToken cancelToken;
  late final Dio dio;

  HttpRequestsImp() {
    cancelToken = CancelToken();
    dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: BASE_API_URL,
      connectTimeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
      receiveTimeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
      contentType: Headers.jsonContentType,
      responseType: ResponseType.json,
    ))
      ..interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
        onRequest: (options, handler) {
          final userCredentials = localStorage.read(USER_CREDENTIALS);
          if (userCredentials != null) {
            final userMapData = jsonDecode(userCredentials);
            options.headers['Authorization'] =
                'Bearer ${userMapData["token"]['accessToken']}';
          }

          return handler.next(options);
        },
        onResponse: (response, handler) {
          return handler.next(
              response); // continue with the response which will be returned
        },
        onError: (DioException e, handler) async {
          if (e.type == DioExceptionType.cancel) {
            log('DioError: ${e.message}');
            return;
          }
          if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
            try {
              final newAccessToken = await getNewAccessToken();
              if (newAccessToken.isNotEmpty) {
                e.requestOptions.headers['Authorization'] =
                    'Bearer $newAccessToken';
                final retryResponse = await dio.request(
                  e.requestOptions.path,
                  options: Options(
                    method: e.requestOptions.method,
                    headers: e.requestOptions.headers,
                  ),
                  data: e.requestOptions.data,
                  queryParameters: e.requestOptions.queryParameters,
                  cancelToken: cancelToken, // Apply cancel token on retry
                );
                return handler.resolve(retryResponse);
              }
            } catch (tokenError) {
              log('Token refresh failed: $tokenError');
              final router = sl<AppRouter>();
              router.push(const Login());
            }
          }
          return handler.next(e);
        },
      ));
  }

  Future<String> getNewAccessToken() async {
    try {
      final userCredentials = localStorage.read(USER_CREDENTIALS);
      final userMapData = jsonDecode(userCredentials);

      final response = await dio.post(
        '/auth/token/refresh',
        data: {'refreshToken': userMapData['token']['refreshToken']},
        cancelToken: cancelToken, // Apply cancel token here as well
      );

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        localStorage.delete(USER_CREDENTIALS);
        final router = sl<AppRouter>();
        router.push(const Login());
        return "";
      } else {
        final data = response.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
        userMapData['token']['accessToken'] = data['payload']['accessToken'];
        userMapData['token']['refreshToken'] = data['payload']['refreshToken'];
        await localStorage.write(USER_CREDENTIALS, jsonEncode(userMapData));

        return data['payload']['accessToken'];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log('Failed to get new access token: $e');
      localStorage.delete(USER_CREDENTIALS);
      final router = sl<AppRouter>();
      router.push(const Login());
      return "";
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> get(String url) async {
    cancelToken.cancel('cancelled');
    print(cancelToken.isCancelled);

    cancelToken = CancelToken();
    final response = await dio.get(url, cancelToken: cancelToken);
    if (response.statusCode! >= 500) {
      throw ServerException(response.data);
    }
    return response;
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> post(String url, {Object? body}) async {
    final response = await dio.post(url, data: body, cancelToken: cancelToken);
    if (response.statusCode! >= 500) {
      throw ServerException(response.data);
    }
    return response;
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> delete(String url) async {
    final response = await dio.delete(url, cancelToken: cancelToken);
    if (response.statusCode! >= 500) {
      throw ServerException(response.data);
    }
    return response;
  }

  @override
  Future<Response> patch(String url, {Object? body}) async {
    final response = await dio.patch(url, data: body, cancelToken: cancelToken);
    if (response.statusCode! >= 500) {
      throw ServerException(response.data);
    }
    return response;
  }

  @override
  void cancelRequests() {}
}
 

